# WPF.NET Different Usercontrolls in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

i have a Datagrid with 2 Columns: Description and value. Description should be displayed as a Textboxcolumn. Value should be displayed as a Textboxcolumn or Comboboxcolumn, based on true or false. 
How it ist possible to change the Usercontrol of the column dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: And how are you binding the data to the datagrid? Paste some code!

Comment: At the moment i have a class

Comment: With 2 Properties and i will bind the class to itemsource of the datagrid

Comment: Have you looked at DataGridTemplateColumn?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be have a DataGridTemplateColumn with the two controls inside and bind its visibility to a property in your item class.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBox Text="{Binding value}" Visibility="{Binding visibilityTextbox}"/>
           <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding options}" Visibility="{Binding visibilityCombobox}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Then in your class:

```
public string value {get;set;}
public ObservableCollection<string> options {get;set;}
public bool isComboBox {get;set;}
public Visibility visibilityTextbox { get { if(isComboBox) { return Visibility.Collapsed; } else { return Visibility.Visible; }} }
public Visibility visibilityCombobox { get { if(isComboBox) { return Visibility.Visible; } else { return Visibility.Collapsed; }} }
```